# Any way to get rid of an obsolete parameter in Azure PowerShell script (AzureRM to Az changing)

Tags: azure, powershell, inline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As you may know, MSFT is getting rid of AzureRM cmdlets in favor of Az.
There are a lot of issues regarding this since the proposed native aliases "Enable-AzureRmAlias" seems to stop being updated.

I have a script based on AzureRM in one repo, that triggers by Azure DevOps release pipeline step function (Azure PowerShell based),

that has the following piece of code:

```
$var = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName-Name $Key).SecretValueText
```

"Enable-AzureRmAlias" command activated as well..., that converts the code like this:

```
$var = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName-Name $Key).SecretValueText
```

The problem is, that ".SecretValueText" was deprecated a while ago. Instead of it, a new parameter has been added to the Get-AzKeyVaultSecret cmdlet - "-AsPlainText"

so... theoretically the final construction has to be like this:

```
$var = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName-Name $Key -AsPlainText
```

Challenges!
I can't upgrade the original script in the repo to Az due to the necessity of back-compatibility.
The only way to solve it - is to create some kind of alias in Azure PowerShell inline script (that triggers the main script in the repo)
I stuck with this ".SecretValueText"

My original idea to put the following into the inline script doesn't seem to be working:

```
function Get-AzKeyVaultSecretNew {
Param(
  $vaultName,
  $Key
     )
   $var = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $Key -AsPlainText
   return $var
} 

Set-Alias -Name Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -Value Get-AzKeyVaultSecretNew
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you can use [Update-TypeData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata?view=powershell-7.1) for the object type that `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` returns to include that property. Possibly do that before your commands run.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try below workaround? How did it go

Answer (score 0):

This should theoretically help your situation. You can run this code at the beginning of the PowerShell session that will be calling your scripts. You will need to make sure any necessary modules are loaded so that the secret object types are loaded.

```
$Script = { Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $this.VaultName -Name $this.Name -AsPlainText }
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.PSKeyVaultSecretIdentityItem' -MemberName 'SecretValueText' -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value $Script
```

The idea is to add the `SecretValueText` property back to the `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.PSKeyVaultSecretIdentityItem` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below workaround to replace below piece of code:

`(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName-Name $Key).SecretValueText`

with `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $Key -AsPlainText` via using [RegEx Find & Replace](https://github.com/knom/vsts-regex-tasks/) task. Check below steps:

1, Add task `RegEx Find & Replace` to replace the orginal code with the converted code. See below:

```
    FindRegex: '\(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName \$vaultName -Name \$Key\)\.SecretValueText'
    ReplaceRegex: 'Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $Key -AsPlainText'
```

[image]

2, `-AsPlainText` parameter is only available in the latest az 5.3.0 version. Since the version installed in cloud agent is 4.7.0. You need to install the az 5.3.0 version before executing your script. See below. Use a powershell task to install az 5.3.0 version.

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Modules" -Name "az_5.3.0" -ItemType "directory"

Save-Module -Name AZ -RequiredVersion 5.3.0 -Path "C:\Modules\az_5.3.0"
```

[image]

3, Then you can invoke your script in the azure powershell task directly.