# Trying to store secrets from one Kv to Another

Tags: azure, powershell

Facing issues with the below code for Copying the secrets from one KV to another. The secrets value always retrieves null.

```
$keyvaultName = 'kv1'
$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName
$kvname='bkpkv2'

$keys =@{}
foreach ($secret in $secrets)
    {
        $secretName = $secret.name
        
        $key = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -name $secretName).SecretValueText
        $keys.Add("$secretName", "$key")


        $hashed = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $key -AsPlainText -Force
        Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $kvname -Name $secret.name -Secretvalue $hashed


    }
```

Comment: Wasn't `SecretValueText` deprecated? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65722400/11025476) for a workaround or use `$key = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -name $secretName -AsPlainText` instead

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of Az, `SecretValueText` is deprecated. If you want to view the decrypted text of a secret, you can use the `-AsPlainText` switch on [Get-AzKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-5.4.0).

```
$secretText = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -name $secretName -AsPlainText
```

---

You may have a situation where the removal of `SecretValueText` property is a breaking change. Then another option is to add `SecretValueText` property back to the `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.PSKeyVaultSecretIdentityItem` objects.

```
# Update the PSKeyVaultSecretIdentityItem object type at the beginning of the session
$Script = { Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $this.VaultName -Name $this.Name -AsPlainText }
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.PSKeyVaultSecretIdentityItem' -MemberName 'SecretValueText' -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value $Script

# SecretValueText property will contain decrypted secret for remainder of the session
$secretText = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -name $secretName).SecretValueText
```